# LESS loop to create modular scale

Tags: less

I am trying to realize a modular approach to text sizing using the following starting variables:

@font-size: 1.7rem;
@line-height: 1.414;

I would like to write a mixin that would create this result but have not quite fully grasped LESS yet:

```
h4 {
    font-size: @font-size * @line-height;
}
h3 {
    font-size: (@font-size * @line-height) * @line-height;
}
h2 {
    font-size: ((@font-size * @line-height) * @line-height) * @line-height;
}
h1 {
    font-size: (((@font-size * @line-height) * @line-height) * @line-height) * @line-height;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an array with your selectors - `@elements`.

Then you get the length of `@elements` - it will be used as iterator through an array.
Then the loop starts. It has the name `set-font-size`. In `Less` loops are recursive mixins. This mixin takes some parameters and calls itself until some condition is correct. In this example, it works while `@_i > 0`. Every time it calls itself, the value of `@_i` decreases.

Inside mixin (or loop) you get current element from array by calling `extract(@array, @index)` command. Then you set the font size to your selector. Evry time mixin call itself, the value of font-size is increased `@_font-size * @_line-height`.

That's all :)
Codepen **[DEMO](https://codepen.io/3rdthemagical/pen/eVQMrE)**.

Less:

```
@elements: h1, h2, h3, h4;

@iterations: length(@elements); // lehgth of @elements

@font-size: 1.7rem;
@line-height: 1.414;

.set-font-size(@_i, @_elements, @_font-size, @_line-height) when (@_i > 0) {  
  @selector: extract(@_elements, @_i);

  @{selector} {
    font-size: @_font-size;
  }

  .set-font-size(@_i - 1, @_elements, @_font-size * @_line-height, @_line-height);
}

.set-font-size(@iterations, @elements, @font-size, @line-height);
```

Css output:

```
h4 {
  font-size: 1.7rem;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 2.4038rem;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 3.3989732rem;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 4.8061481rem;
}
```